# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED while accessing an image file on local network

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have 2 websites running in my IIS in one machine. One is the PHP website and another is the ASP.NET WebApi. The PHP site is my family website which is kind of an adapter between HTML and WebAPI. Now, in my PHP site I have a page which loads all family pictures from a selected folder on my home wifi network.

If I browse PHP site from the same machine where API is hosted then everything works great. But when I browse my PHP site from other machine in my home wifi network I see `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

As far as the permisssions are concerned I have IUSR full control over my image folder.

Any idea where I am missing the mark?

Answer (score 0):

Your Internet is not working or the server is not set up to receive http request